# How can i print 'bloginfo('url')' on a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I do not want to enter www.domain.cl on the page, but to have a constant that contains the value www.domain.cl. For example:

the
`HTML <a href="www.domino.cl">HOME</a>`

to `<a href="const">HOME</a>`

Answer (score 1):

On WordPress the solution is:

```
 <?php
 <a href='<?php echo bloginfo("url ") ; ?>'>HOME</a>
 ?>
```

Or

```
 <?php
 <a href='<?php echo site_url() ; ?>'>HOME</a>
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP Constant. See the below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_constants.asp

So, you can get the site name in any of your files.

Put the below code in your header.php file.

```
<?php
    $siteName = site_url();
    define( 'SITE_NAME', $siteName );
?>
```

and, you can get the Site URL like this.

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>">HOME</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for reference

```
 <?php
 $url = "www.domino.cl";
 ?>

 <a href='<?php echo $url; ?>'>HOME</a>
```

OR

```
<?php
const URL = "www.domino.cl";
?>
<a href='<?php echo URL; ?>'>HOME</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for reference:-

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>">home</a>

OR

<a href=" <?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom function km_get_blog_posts_page_url() in functions.php file. Please refer below link.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Get blog posts page URL.
 *
 * @return string The blog posts page URL.
 */
function km_get_blog_posts_page_url() {
    // If front page is set to display a static page, get the URL of the posts page.
    if ( 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
        return get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
    }
    // The front page IS the posts page. Get its URL.
    return get_home_url();
}
```

This is the [source](https://gist.github.com/kellenmace/9ef19dd86580cb7e63720b396c8c2721) of the above code.